# what is wrong in this batch?

Tags: apex, batch, query, custom-object, integration

```
global class ALN_Integration_Batch implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {

        for (ALN_Integration__c recAln : lstCon) {
            AccountContactRelation acr = new AccountContactRelation();
            acr.AccountId = accPmcMap.get(recAln.Property__c).Id;
            acr.ContactId = conMap.(recAln.First_Name__c + recAln.Last_name__c + recAln.Email__c).Id;                             
        } 
   }
        global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){}
        
}
```

Comment: I'm glad that you've received an excellent answer but want to direct you to [ask]. Please ensure that each post contains not just code, but a detailed and specific problem statement, along with a minimal amount of code to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to insert the records you were creating:

```
ALN_Integration__c[] alnIntegrationRecords = new ALN_Integration__c[0];
for (ALN_Integration__c recAln : lstCon) {
    AccountContactRelation acr = new AccountContactRelation();
    acr.AccountId = accPmcMap.get(recAln.Property__c).Id;
    acr.ContactId = conMap.(recAln.First_Name__c + recAln.Last_name__c + recAln.Email__c).Id;                             
    alnIntegrationRecords.add(acr);
} 
insert alnIntegrationRecords;
```

You may have other problems as well, but we'd need more information to assist you.